# how to choose beacon uuid?

Tags: uuid, beacon

Have a question about beacon uuid.

If a want to avoid uuid conflict with an existing one, is there a standard or a central service to choose my uuid, and then make sure that my app will be notified with only my beacons ?

Thank you

Comment: I believe this has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243769/what-range-of-bluetooth-uuids-can-be-used-for-vendor-defined-profiles

Comment: I don't think that question is really the same -- the question linked above is about CBUUIDs which is a quite different use case than using an iBeacon UUID.  I stand by my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33898804/1461050 despite it getting a downvote by somebody who misunderstood what I said.  Please check out my answer and upvote.